# How to correct the text alignment of a Lottie file?

Tags: android, json, lottie

My designer gave me a Lottie (json) file and it contains text.

Other images are shown correctly, but the text is not. It must be at the center but is at the right side.

Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/388#issuecomment-397545361). And one solution is changing text to shape and render it again. However, it is not the right solution. And it makes the size bigger.

This issue doesn't happen on the web, only on Android and iOS.

In the json file, there are many options or attributes that I might be able to manipulate the image or text of the lottie animation.

Such as `v`, `fr`, `ip`, `op`, `w`, `h`, `nm`, `ddd`, `assets`, `layers`, `makers`.

And in the `assets`, There are `id`, `w`, `h`, `u`, `p`, `e`.
In the `layers`, There are layers and a layer contains `ddd`, `ind`, `ty`, `nm`, `sr`, `ks`, `ao`, `shapes`, `ip`, `op`, `st`, `bm`.

It's so confusing. Is there any ways to solve this issue?

Comment: like one guy in the commenst said:
You need to convert text to Shape in order to render the text correctly.

Comment: @PembaTamang like one guy in the comment said: It is not a right solution.

Comment: @PembaTamang It works but I want the real solution.

Comment: ok have you done it now??

Comment: `instead of dragging text box from tools to the canvas, just double click on text icon. And then start typing in the text box. Then you can move it to your desired place in the canvas. Ik its pretty weird but this way my alignment was fixed when I last tried it` can be one solution. But haven't found the solution with manipulating the json code.

Comment: I have never tried manipulating the json....never quite understood it. Well the thing is that everything must be vectorized in order for bodymovin to render it properly. I do not hire designers I do it myslef, I spent a few days on youtube seeing some basic videos now I  can make decent  animations myself. It is more fun u know

Answer (score 1):

The `j` property stands for text justification.

Comment: What is that for?

Comment: To change the text alignment you need to update the "j" property of the text layer in your JSON file. To get the text centered set the value to "2".

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in the lottie named

```
"j":"some_integer"
```

You can change that to 1, -1 or 0. 1 -> for left alignment. -1 -> for center alignment. 0 -> for right alignment.